# How to change the position of monitor on dual monitor display setup in Windows using the command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, multiple-monitors, nircmd

I've managed to create 2 bat files that switches between primary displays (Display 1 and Display 2).

I did this to simplify the process of running a dual-monitor splitscreen configuration for Rocket League.

However, my displays are physically at 2 seperate heights and I still need to adjust the position of the monitors in 'Display Settings' to make this work properly.

Is there a way to adjust the vertical positioning of one of my displays via CMD so I can include it in my Bat file?

---

**Default.bat**: Replacing the config in Rocket League directory with Default config and changing default monitor to '1'.

```
echo f | xcopy /s "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Default\TASystemSettings.ini" "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League\TAGame\Config\TASystemSettings.ini" /y && nircmd setprimarydisplay 1 && echo f | xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Splitscreen\Splitscreen.bat" "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Switch.bat" && exit
```

---

**Splitscreen.bat**: Replacing the config in Rocket League directory with modified config and changing default monitor to '2'.

```
echo f | xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Splitscreen\TASystemSettings.ini" "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League\TAGame\Config\TASystemSettings.ini" && nircmd setprimarydisplay 2 && echo f | xcopy /s/y "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Default\Default.bat" "C:\Users\TheMr\Documents\My Games\Rocket League Configs\Switch.bat" && exit
```

---

They both replace the `Switch.bat` file to the opposite configuration `.bat` so I only have one file to click on.

Ideally, I'd like to have a bat file with a counter so if the counter is '0', it executes one line of code and if it was '1' then it would run the other, but I'm not sure that is possible. This would just eliminate having 3 files to execute one task.

Comment: Can you add the commands you are using to switch the displays?

Comment: @uSlackr Updated post.